# Could not find sslCommerzSdk

Tags: android

I want to implement SSL Commerz payment gateway in myproject. I add all ncessary dependency to the build.gradle (app module) follow their documentation. I use sslCommerzSdk.aar file in libs. But an error is shown that Could not find :sslCommerzSdk:. Required by: project :app
This is my build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.buscard"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.5.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation (name: 'sslCommerzSdk', ext:'aar')

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imdiu.png
```

Answer (score 0):

20/03/2023

For new android project instead of using:
repositories {
flatDir {
dirs 'libs'
}
}
implementation (name: 'sslCommerzSdk', ext:'aar')

**Just use:**
implementation files("libs/sslCommerzSdk.aar")

in your build.gradle